# drupal migration - update content rather than import

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration, database-migration

I have content that exists on the staging site and I need to bring it across onto the live site. The issue that I am experiencing is that the staging site and the live site have gone out of sync and when I import content from staging into live it produces duplicates. I was wondering if there was a way to check if the content exists and if it does to then update it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of options depending on your specific scenario, content types and site setup. A few recommended modules you can try are:

- [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export)
- [Drupal Sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_sync)

Also check on the drupal stackexchange and you will find many resources for similar question asked in the past. Some of them are

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/sync-content-between-two-drupal-sites
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131887/how-to-export-and-import-nodes-in-bulk